# Python3 ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following 3 python files:

- `main.py`

```py
from .Constants import *
```

- `__init__.py`
- `Constants.py`:

```py
CONSTANT_TEST = test
```

Now when I run `python3 main.py` i get the following error

```sh
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of thumb is that you should never execute files from within the same package. My suggestion would be to create a test file and import your package into that file, then do all of your testing from within that file. For example, if your package directory looks like this:

```
package_tests.py

package/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    Constants.py
```

In `package/__init__.py`:

```
from package.Constants import CONSTANT_TEST

# import everything here that you want users to be able to access by topmost import ("import package")
```

In `package/Constants.py`:

```
CONSTANT_TEST = "constant"
```

In `package/main.py`:

```
from package.Constants import CONSTANT_TEST

# other code that utilizes CONSTANT_TEST
```

In `package_tests.py`:

```
import package

print(package.CONSTANT_TEST)
```